# How to show that the image of a rational map is open?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive group and $T$ a maximal torus of $G$. Let $B$ be a Borel subgroup of $G$ containing $T$. Let $U$ be the unipotent radical of $B$. Let $g \in G$. Suppose that $g \in B w B$ for some $w \in W$, $W$ is the Weyl group of $G$. Define a rational map $f: G \to U$ by $g \mapsto x^{-1} y$, where $g=x \overline{w} t y$, $x, y \in U$, $t \in T$. I think that the image of $f$ is open. Usually how to show that the image of a rational map is open? Thank you very much.

Edit: how to show that the image of $f|_{B^-}: B^- \to U$ given by $g =x \overline{w} t y \mapsto x^{-1} y$ is open? Let $g=x \overline{w} t y \in B^-$. Then $y$ depends on $x$. If $y$ does not depend on $x$, then it is easy to see that the image of $f|_{B^-}$ is $U$ and hence the image of $f|_{B^-}$ is open. But now $y$ depends on $x$. How to show that the image of $f|_{B^-}$ is open? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your map really well defined ? I can take $x' = x, \overline{w}' = \overline{w}, t' = 1$ and $y' = ty$.

Comment: The rational map $f : G \rightarrow U$ is definitely surjective. Also if the rational map is defined on a bigger open set than the big cell, the image of $f$ will still land inside $U$, since $U$ is a closed subgroup. But the image is already $U$.

Comment: @random123, thank you very much. I edited the text. How to show that the image of $f|_{B^-}$ is open?

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet, $y' = ty \not\in U$. $f$ is a rational map and its domain is $\cup_{w \in W} BwB = \cup_{w \in W} U \overline{w} TU$.